# Summernote HTML editor and Fancybox 3 usage

Tags: fancybox, summernote

I faced with a problem while using Summernote HTML editor and Fancybox 3 together. When i`m trying to open fancy image, it start to blink.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVh2G.gif)

How to fix this problem? Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Live demo would help to give an answer.

Comment: I have tried to simulate my problem on Codepen just using summernote and fancybox, but there everything works fine, so the problem not in conflict between  plugins. Question closed, thanks.

Comment: Try to disable open and close effects, set `openEffect  : 'none'` and `closeEffect : 'none'`